# HereMaps JS api failure

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm getting an error when I attempt to use HereMap API

This line fails:

```
new H.service.Platform({ apiKey: MY-KEY })
```

Here are the relevant stacks:

```
mapsjs-core.js:130 Uncaught TypeError: a.jj is not a function
    at new Rg (mapsjs-core.js:130)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (mapsjs-core.js:71), <anonymous>:102:126)
    at Object.eval (mapsjs-core.js:71)
    at mapsjs-service.js:7

Uncaught InvalidArgumentError: H.geo.Point (Argument #0 undefined)
    at new D (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:43:977)
    at Rf (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:85:714)
    at new Wf (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:86:74)
    at Yf (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:90:49)
    at Th.sg (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:173:573)
    at new Th (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:173:454)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:71:36), <anonymous>:78:515)
    at Object.eval (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:71:36)
    at https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js:7:8

VM360:44 Uncaught TypeError: Un is not a function
    at X.Kk (eval at <anonymous> (mapsjs-core.js:71), <anonymous>:44:734)
    at new X (eval at <anonymous> (mapsjs-core.js:71), <anonymous>:44:474)
    at getPlatform (here-map-wrapper.js:9)
```

Looks like this same error is happening right now on the demo site as well:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/maps/map-at-specified-location

Any work around options or way we might subscribe to updates?

### Update

Looks like the issue has slightly changed

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.a.Bb is not a function
    at new cp (eval at <anonymous> (mapsjs-core.js:71), <anonymous>:21:767)
    at Module.createHereMapInstance (here-map-wrapper.js:42)
```

Line of failing code is now:

```
const behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
```

Comment: what browser and browser version are you on? I've got many users reporting this issue today, I think it's on the HERE maps side, but I can't replicated it myself. I'm about to purchase a browserstack subscription, I'm curious what your browser and version are that you are getting the error.

Comment: Google Chrome Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Looks like it is working in Safari (Version 13.0.5 (15608.5.11))

Comment: It's working for me in Chrome 80. That's so odd. It's very intermittent, I would say its happening to maybe 2% of our users. Some of them have been in Firefox and I had them switch to Chrome and it worked fine in Chrome, and some vice versa, they had this JS error in Chrome and then I had them try FireFox and it worked in Firefox.

Comment: I think it has to be on their end, but I don't see any way to communicate with them without having an enterprise developer plan, which we do not have.

Comment: @Luke, it looks like caching issue. It's working fine for me in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge browsers. Also examples on developer.here.com work fine.
Is it still happening for you?

Comment: @Tomas looks to be working now! Is there anything we should be doing on our end to help avoid this? Like invalidating browser cookies or something?

Comment: I'm still having users with this issue. Again, not affecting all users but some. I've had them clear cache, even done it for them via remote access, and still having error.

Comment: @Luke sorry for the late response. Missed your comment. To ensure the continuity and no disruption when the library version is updated on the CDN, you can use the full version (`3.1.15.1` at the time of writing this) instead of evergreen `3.1` as noted here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.15.1/dev_guide/topics/api-versions.html#versions-on-the-cdn.

Answer (score 0):

I have users reporting this same thing (the letters in the error are different, but same type of error). 1 on FireFox, 1 on Chrome, both just started yesterday or today. But we didn't change anything our site.

On my personal chrome and firefox, this error does not show, though. Nor my other developers computer. But I have multiple clients with this issue today.

I tried to trace it and it seems to trigger on this line of JS in particular:
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: this.a.zb is not a function
at new fp (eval at <anonymous>)  ---- (map-js-core:70), <anonymous>:21:767
at showOrderMap ----- this points to the behavior event noted above